# How Can i echo the real time value of range slider on different php page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a paper slider in my index.php page. I am able to get the real time value of paper slider and display its value in input type=text... of form ,textarea...  and div.

What i want is to echo the real time of values of this slider in another php page.for eg: value.php
Is there any way I can do it?

I will be very grateful.

Here is my Code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>paper-input</title>
  <script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  <link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-slider/paper-slider.html" rel="import"> 
  <link href="https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/font-roboto/roboto.html" rel="import"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">

  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  
 <style shim-shadowdom>
  body{
      font-family: RobotoDraft, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 24px;
  }
    
  paper-slider {
      width: 100%;
  }
    
  section {
      max-width: 1000px;
      padding: 20px 0;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
  }
    
  section > div {
      padding: 14px;
  }
    
  .yellow-slider paper-slider::shadow #sliderKnobInner,
  .yellow-slider paper-slider::shadow #sliderBar::shadow #activeProgress {
     background-color: #f4b400;
  }
    
  .green-slider paper-slider::shadow #sliderKnobInner,
  .green-slider paper-slider::shadow #sliderKnobInner::before,
  .green-slider paper-slider::shadow #sliderBar::shadow #activeProgress {
      background-color: #0f9d58;
  }
    
  #ratingsLabel {
      padding-left: 12px;
      color: #a0a0a0;
  }
    
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="valueslide"></div>
    <form role="form" method="POST">
        <textarea id="mytextarea" name="slider">Text to be changed</textarea>
    </form>
    <table>
    <!--tr specifies a new row-->
        <tr>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td><input type=text id='firstNumber' value=''></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <template is="auto-binding">
        <paper-slider on-immediate-value-change="{{sliderChange}}" min="0" max='100' pin immediateValue="{{sliderValue}}"></paper-slider>
 </template>
</body>
<script>
  document.querySelector('template').addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
      this.sliderChange = function() {
        var x=(this.sliderValue);
     var n = x.toString();
     document.getElementById("valueslide").innerHTML=x;
  document.getElementById('mytextarea').innerHTML =x;
  document.getElementById('firstNumber').value =n;
      };
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options here.

1. *AJAX*: you would publish by AJAX any changes to your server when the change event is fired. You could store the value in a DB or some other data store. The subscriber page would then poll for changes to that data store and retrieve the new value (again by AJAX).
   **Pros**: Easy to implement
   **Cons**: you'd be constant opening and closing connections and you'd need to manage the order of responses carefully.
2. *Web Sockets*: you would open a web socket to the server and publish changes, the subscriber would also have a web socket connection open, so the server would pass the value on.
   **Pros**: Very fast and no need to closely manage connections
   **Cons**: Limited browser support and PHP is not suited to the task (NodeJS is your friend here)
3. *Firebase* (other services are available): probably the ideal solution would be to use a 3rd pub/sub such as [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com) that do the hard stuff of option 2, but with the fallback of option 1.
   **Pros**: takes the difficult stuff off your plate, easy to implement, fast
   **Cons**: 3rd party

Comment: I have little knowledge about ajax.It will be very grateful if u can hint me on how to do it with ajax.

Comment: To do it by AJAX, create a JS event handler on the slider to fire on change. When fired, use something like [`jQuery.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to send the data to the PHP script. In the PHP script, store the value somewhere (DB, cache, memcached etc). On the client, use something like `setinterval` to periodically use something like `jQuery.get` or `jQuery.getJSON` or the base `jQuery.ajax` to call the PHP script that would then retrieve the value from the data store and spit it back out. The JS would then take this and display it on the page. Simplest would be Firebase option